# Clarifying Dirac's theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

***Theorem** : If $G$ is a simple graph with $n$ vertices with $ n ≥ 3$ such that the
degree of every vertex in G is at least $ n/2$, then $G$ has a Hamilton circuit.*

In this if $n$ is odd, should I consider the greatest integer not exceeding $n/2$ or least integer greater than $n/2$?

Comment: Greatest integer not exceeding $n/2$ is not enough in general: consider a path on $3$ vertices.

Comment: @Casteels What if n>3? then can the greatest integer be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalizing my comment, consider the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n-1}$. This graph is not Hamiltonian since a Hamiltonian cycle would be of odd length. On the other hand, the degree of every vertex is at least $n-1$, which is the greatest integer not exceeding $\frac{2n-1}{2}$.

So to answer your question, you need to take the ceiling of $\frac{|V(G)|}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why this has not been mentioned in the theorem!

Comment: It doesn't need to be mentioned. The degree $d$ of a vertex is an **integer**, so $d\ge x$ is **equivalent** to $d\ge\lceil x\rceil$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the greatest integer not exceeding n/2 will suffice when n is odd because the sum of degrees of any two vertices will be at least n-1 and the existence of a Hamiltonian circuit follows from Ore's Theorem

Comment: As mentioned in the comment by Casteels I guess this is not correct when n=3.